# How to see which unit test failed

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I am new to Karma/Jasmine unit test platform and I am working on an existing Angular project which uses Karma/Jasmine for unit tests. This is a large project and there are approx 2000 unit tests which need to run.

When running the unit test the console window just runs through all the tests, super fast, how do I go back an see the details about a test that failed?

Also, is there is a way to only run a specific test, so that I dont need to run all 2000 tests each time?

Comment: The name of the failing tests is printed in the console. read what is printed. To execute a single test, name it `iit` instead of `it()` (or `ddescribe()` instead of `describe()` if you want to run a single test suite).

Answer (score 0):

try to take this appratch - [Karma runner console - output only failed tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18121197/karma-runner-console-output-only-failed-tests)

In fact you have to change your karma config to "dots"

// possible values: dots || progress || growl

```
reporters: ['dots', 'junit'],
```